# Angular-CLI - how to replace some string in files before distribution, based on environment

Tags: angular, tfs, asp.net-core, angular-cli

Initially, I was using Angular VS 2017 template with Angular 2.4.0 and `webpack`.

Due to some problems with upgrading to Angular 4, I decided to switch to Angular-CLI(angular 4) and net.core 2.0 app. My app is set up and running.

I am using TFS for build, and based on environment I have few different settings files in my angular app:

- app.settings.debug.ts
- app.settings.release.ts
- app.settings.ts

I am importing these files based on environment to fill Auth Configuration:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AppSettings } from '../../app.settings';

@Injectable()
export class AuthConfiguration {

    // The Issuer Identifier for the OpenID Provider (which is typically obtained during Discovery) MUST exactly match the value of the iss (issuer) Claim.
    public iss = AppSettings.API_AUTH_URL;

    public server = AppSettings.API_AUTH_URL;

    public redirect_url = AppSettings.WEBAPP_URL;

    // This is required to get the signing keys so that the signiture of the Jwt can be validated.
    public jwks_url = AppSettings.API_AUTH_URL + '/.well-known/openid-configuration/jwks';

    // The Client MUST validate that the aud (audience) Claim contains its client_id value registered at the Issuer identified by the iss (issuer) Claim as an audience.
    // The ID Token MUST be rejected if the ID Token does not list the Client as a valid audience, or if it contains additional audiences not trusted by the Client.
    public client_id = 'angular2client';

    public response_type = 'id_token token';

    public scope = 'api openid profile';

    public post_logout_redirect_uri = AppSettings.WEBAPP_URL;
}
```

In old project I've used webpack to replace this part based on environment:

```
import { AppSettings } from '../../app.settings';
```

like this in webpack.config.js:

```
 { test: /\.ts$/, include: /ClientApp/, use: [{ loader: 'string-replace-loader', query: { search: '/app.settings', replace: isLocalhost ? '/app.settings' : isDebug ? '/app.settings.debug' : '/app.settings.release' }, }, 'awesome-typescript-loader?silent=true', 'angular2-template-loader',] },
```

How can I achieve this with angular-CLI and packages.json?

I would love to achieve the same behavior as now, wherein TFS build I have an NPM task with the command from package.json for example, `npm build debug` or `npm build release` for each environment respectively.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the environment files of angular cli in (src/environments)

```
// src/environments/environment.ts
export const environment = {
    API_AUTH_URL: 'auth_url'
}
```

Then in your typescript, import the variable and use as needed

```
// service.ts
import { environment } from './environments/environment';

@Injectable()
export class AuthConfiguration {
    public iss = environment.API_AUTH_URL;
}
```

To use the environment file you can make an npm script

```
"build-dev": "ng build --environment=dev"
```

Note: if you do not specify the environment, the cli will use the default environment that is defined in the angular-cli.json in `{"apps": [{"environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts"}]}`

The cli also allows you to add additional environment files. For example you can add src/environments/environment.release.ts, then in your angular-cli.json, you would add

```
{
    "apps": [{
        ...,
        "environments": {
            ...,
            "release": "environments/environment.release.ts"
        }
    }]
}
```

Now you can make an additional npm script to use your custom environment file

```
"build-release": "ng build --environment=release"
```

Here is a pretty good article covering the above. http://tattoocoder.com/angular-cli-using-the-environment-option/

Comment: If I want to load release file which in this case is environment.release.ts does any change in service.ts file has to be done? Or IT stays the same import? In that case there is no need for string replace

Comment: @AmelSalibasic the same import. the cli/webpack will handle what to use, so the import is always `/environments/environment`

Comment: This thing works perfectly, thanks for taking time and answering step by step. I want to mention for anyone else coming here, for actual serve with environmental values use `ng serve --env=NAME_OF_ENVIRONMENT`, for build into distro folder use `ng build --env=NAME_OF_ENVIRONMENT` .

Comment: I really don't like solutions where the "compiled" bundle is different for each environment. It fails a key DevOps principle that states a deployable software asset should be transferrable across environments without binary modification. If this config is environment-specific then opt to use HTTP to serve the JSON dynamically and keep your bundle's environment agnostic.